# Creating a dictionary of dictionaries from groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    Friend A        Friend B    Score
0    Walter          John        22
1    Walter          Jack        32
2    Fred            John        10
3    Caleb           Jack        5
```

What I'd like to produce is this:

```
{"Walter": {"John": 22, "Jack": 32}, "Fred": {"John": 10}, "Caleb": {"Jack": 5}}
```

What I have so far is this:

```
x = Network.groupby("Friend A")[["Friend A", "Friend B", "Score"]]
```

I've tried doing the following:

```
x.apply(list).to_dict()
```

But this isn't the result I'd like to get. How can I achieve this result?

Comment: Why do you want this dict of dicts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [17]: df.groupby("Friend A").apply(lambda x: x.set_index("Friend B")['Score'].to_dict()).to_dict()

Out[17]:
{'Caleb': {'Jack': 5},
 'Fred': {'John': 10},
 'Walter': {'Jack': 32, 'John': 22}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
a = Network.groupby("Friend A").apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x["Friend B"], x["Score"]))).to_dict()
```